# Looping bubbles animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm working on a react website but new to the animation area.

I'm trying to accomplish the effect like the hero section of this page: https://stripe.com/us/customers, where there's an infinite loop of circles scrolling from right to left, each with different images and sizes.

How should I get started with this infinite loop of objects animation using React? Is there some library that I can use, or is there a react code snippet sample that I can learn from?

Comment: inspect it in chrome and I find that it's using translate to move the div bubbles. one way I am thinking of is using a container to save the state of all bubbles and update the position of the bubble and re render them every certain amount of time

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to accomplish this using purely CSS (check out these crazy pure CSS animation examples that you can fork https://envato.com/blog/pure-css-animation-snippets/)

But the ReactJS approach would be to create a component like.. lets say FloatingIcon

```
 import React from 'react';

 class FloatingIcon extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state{
       horizontalPosition: "0px",
       verticalPosition: "0px",
       imgRef: "http://blah.com/asdf",
       backgroundColor: "#000000"
    }

 }

 changePosition(horizontalPosition, verticalPosition) {
    this.setState({
       horizontalPosition,
       verticalPosition
    });
  }

 render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <img 
           href={this.state.imgRef}
           style={
              {translate(this.state.horizontalPosition,
               this.state.verticalPosition)}, 
               backgroungColor:{this.state.backgroundColor}}>
        </img>
     </div>
    );
 }
}

export default FloatingIcon;
```

each floating icon has an image, background-color, and position in it's state. Create as many as you need for your page and store them in an array. You can change the position using the changePosition function that sets the state and updates causing the DOM to render again. Getting it to float all pretty will take some work, but if you calculate correctly and create a good position change. This will work in a React technical sense and this is a React like design for such a problem creating components to accomplish these tasks using single responsibility principles. Let me know how it goes. Hope this helps friend.

Cheers!

Comment: change bubble position using translateX is better than using left considering performance